# Disable automatic phone number linking in iOS Safari

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari

On my iPhone, Safari sometimes thinks that some sequences of numbers are phone numbers, and automatically formats them as links to call that phone number. For example, if you read this question on an iPhone, the number sequence 7844589738 will be formatted as a phone number even though it isn't meant to be.

I find this particularly annoying since a lot of number sequences on pages I visit aren't actually phone numbers, but other number sequences like IP addresses, post IDs, etc, and I have never called a phone number that I found on a website. So I would like to disable this feature, but I can't find any setting that does so.

I searched the web for a way to disable this, but all I found were pages that explain how to disable it on my site on all iPhones (using HTML and stuff like that), but I want to disable it on *my* iPhone on *all* sites.

Is there a way to keep iOS Safari from automatically formatting number sequences as phone numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not possible on Safari or any other stock application. The only way this is possible if the website developer adds some Meta Data code.

Related:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8185290?answerId=32662540022#32662540022